# Can I get the ABI and contract code from the deployed address?

Tags: solidity

If I have the address of the solidity contract, can I from that address determine the source code and the ABI?

I mean by this, is there a function to call in etherscan or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both are documented here: https://etherscan.io/apis#contracts.

In short, to get the ABI:

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

and to get the source code:

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

Comment: Does this to be be verified? I guessed that would be possible. But I am dynamically deploying code so the contracts will not be verified.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your scenario. You're the one deploying the code, but you don't have the source code and ABI? Certainly Etherscan can't tell you the source code if no one has given Etherscan the source code. :-)

Comment: No, my UI, but the users write their own code from generated options. They do not write the solidity but generate it. But I do not see the code itself directly. I can store it off chain, but I wondered if ethereum had a option for this. I guess not.

Comment: @TrevorOakley if you see the code, then just run it trough `solc` and get the abi methods array

Comment: Yes of course, I understand that can be done. Thanks.